# charts.js show dates 1 year

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I set up a statistics page and I try to display the dates on 1 year (example: January 2018, February 2018 ....) on the X axis and on the Y axis a figure of case. All this with the charts.js library. I try to do this like this:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: getPreviousMonths()
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chiffre d\'affaire - année 2018'
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'month'
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Date'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'value'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});

function getPreviousMonths() {
  var months = [];

  for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    var month = moment().subtract(i, 'months').format('MMMM Y');
    months.push(month);
  }
  return months.reverse();
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

[image: dates]

Comment: So what happens exactly? Does the chart not appear at all or are the dates wrong? An image could be very useful to understand what's going on.

Comment: The dates are wrong it would have to show January 2018 / February 2018 / ....

Comment: So what does it show? Nothing?

Comment: I added it to my post

Comment: Very well done! So is the problem the starting month? It should start with January you mean right?

Comment: Yes January of the current year

Comment: Remove the formatting (`format('MMMM Y')`) or use an `RFC2822` or ISO format (`toISOString()`) for the `xAxes`. The reason why it's not working on some browser is because when given non standard format the `moment` construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. `Chartjs` relies on `Moment.js` for its time scale...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a bit of trying I've found a solution that could be tailored perfectly for you needs.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: getPreviousMonths(),
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chiffre d\'affaire - année 2018'
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'month'
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Date'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'value'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});

function getPreviousMonths() {
  var months = [];
  months = Array.apply(0, Array(12)).map(function(_,i){return moment().month(i).toISOString()})
  return months;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

This is the same function you had but uses the function `moment().month()` that returns an array of months and it formats it with the format you wanted. (It shows only half months in this snippet because it can't extent through the entire page and cuts half months, should work on a full window)

I really don't understand why your code was not working, I guess something happens when you reverse the order but anyway this should work. Cheers!

**=== EDIT ===**

As suggested in the comments, the formatting was removed and was added the function `toISOString()`. This is because before, the date was getting transformed to a jsDate which is not supported by all browsers.

Comment: [Your code doesn't appear to work either.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7847l.png) (I'm using Firefox 62.0.3)

Comment: @timclutton you are right, I just tryied it in Firefox and it doesn't show. Sorry for the problem but I usually just test it with Chrome...let me try to find a better solution!

Comment: @timclutton I think I found a good enough solution in the last edit, check it out!